# Estimated framerate for custom engine?

Tags: c++, directx11

I've been writing my own engine with C++ and DirectX 11. I've got 3d models loaded in with diffuse maps, normal maps, and shadows. There's other things with the engine but my question doesn't pertain to those parts. What estimated framerate should I be getting from a simple cube with all the maps on it. And a moving shadow? Obviously my computer specs make the biggest difference. But lets say anywhere from Nvidia 500 series to 700. Personally I have a GT 750m. So whats a rough estimate of framerate to be getting? Dont want to keep building something that has a major framerate flaw.

Comment: How about measuring it?

Comment: I have measured it. It runs at a little over 200fps. I want to know others framerates to see if thats any good.

Comment: Is that framerate good for your purposes?

Comment: does it really matter? I mean as long as you are above 60fps, continue development, and as soon as you got under it, start optimizing.

Comment: Never measure performance in FPS, always measure it in frame time. For example If drawing one cube gives you 500FPS and drawing 2 cubes gives you 250FPS this seems like a crazy performance impact. While converted to the time it takes to render a single frame you go from 2ms to 4ms. Which is super sensible as you're drawing twice as much :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play some game with your system. Check FPS you are getting. Analyze what is on the screen of the game and compare to yours. If your one cube is rendering slower than game screen, you are obviously doing something wrong.

I would expect one cube with all the normal stuff applied running atleast 500-1000fps on my computer. I can run games like Battlefield 4 with 50+ steady FPS.

Why are you developing an engine? Create a game for it and if it does not run with your system, you can start thinking about optimizations. I consider you graphic card as low end and thus, if your game runs on it, it should run on most of the gamers computers.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Once I added the shadows it dropped from around 500 to 200 fps. Mostly developing it as a learning experience, Im just a junior in highschool so if it turns into something more great.

Comment: I tried loading the Atlas from Titanfall and the framerate didnt change at all. So I was a little confused. Once I added like 8 more of them it went to 60fps?

Comment: I would imagine it being high detailed model, so obviously now you can start checking what areas could be optimized for it to run better. It's not easy to develop 3D engine, so don't be too hard on yourself, do your best, try to learn while doing it and have fun.